# Securing RESTful Web Services Using Java Security Annotations

Tags: java, web-services, security, restful-authentication

Need to implement security to my web services using annotations. Can anyone help me in finding the good url which has all the details to configure security.

Comment: other than adding annotations @RolewAllowed what else i need to do

Comment: can anyone help me please